# How do I convert a string to an int type in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am taking a string value from a textbox named `txtLastAppointmentNo` and
I want to convert it to an `int` and then store it in a database using Linq to sql but I am getting error "input string was not in proper format".

My input string is 2.

My code is:

```
      objnew.lastAppointmentNo=Convert.ToInt32(txtLastAppointmenNo.Text);
```

Please point out my mistake.

Comment: You need to show us the input string causing the error!

Comment: What value contains txtLastAppointmenNo? And may be you should provide to the Convert.ToInt32() txtLastAppointmenNo.Text ?

Comment: i have written it .text in code but still there is problem.....

this error Has made me crazy i dont know whats wrong. there.... :(

Comment: Use the debugger to see what the value of `txtLastAppointmentNo.Text` actually is. I'm guessing it's not what you think it *is* - maybe an empty string.

Comment: Do you have the dot in the string? ie. "2."? or just the 2, ie. "2"?

Comment: @kent I have allow null in database table so thats not the problem..

Comment: @lasse i have tried every thing thats not the case here...

I don't know whats the problem as.....

Comment: @Nauman: if `txtLastAppointmentNo.Text` is an empty string then that *is* the problem. Regardless of whether the underlying database supports `null` in that column, the `Convert.ToInt32` method does *not* support converting `""` to an `int` - it throws an exception with the exact message you describe. **You still haven't told us what the actual string is that is being parsed.** I don't understand: are you afraid to look?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you are using WebForms, then you just need to access the textbox value and not the textbox itself:

```
objnew.lastAppointmentNo = Convert.ToInt32(txtLastAppointmenNo.Text);
```

Or if you are referencing the HTML control then:

```
objnew.lastAppointmentNo = Convert.ToInt32(Request["txtLastAppointmenNo"]);
```

Comment: and would recommend some form of validation as well (e.g. Regex Validator)

Comment: sorry i forget type in .Text here in Q. I have done it in code but still there is error.

Comment: @nonnb +1 for that! @Nauman - Are you setting a breakpoint on that line of code and verifying the input?

Answer (score 4):

You can also go for `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse` or `Convert.ToInt32`

```
//int.Parse
int num = int.Parse(text);
//Convert.ToInt32
int num = Convert.ToInt32(text);

//int.TryParse
string text1 = "x";
        int num1;
        bool res = int.TryParse(text1, out num1);
        if (res == false)
        {
            // String is not a number.
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was an empty string!

In `objnew.lastAppointmentNo=Convert.ToInt32(txtLastAppointmenNo.Text);`, `txtLastAppointmenNo.Text` was an empty value.